# C# / Json.net / how can i deserialize the message?

Tags: c#, dictionary, json.net, deserialization

please help me on what i need to do next? i need this message to be inside their dedicated strings
but i got no idea how to do it

also how about using a dictionary?

the message that i receive is this.. its inside a string called sServerResponse

```
{"pcname": "Kat", "pause": [], "ip": "192.168.1.100", "paused": 0, "services": [], "session": "", "shop": [], "end": 0, "used": 0, "start": 0, "timeup": 0, "follow": "sui", "consq": {"1": "basic", "3": "rounding", "2": "minimum"}, "stas": 0, "price": 0, "pc_status": 1, "account_details": {"3": "Member", "2": "Staff/Member", "4": "Timecode"}, "msg": "Connection/Update accepted.", "mac": "00112233445", "others": [], "remarks": "", "ticker": {"units": 1}, "fixed_time": [], "account": "", "pause_tmp": {"s": 0, "e": 0}, "ver": {}, "status_details": {"1": "Idle", "0": "Offline", "5": "Fixed", "4": "Open", "7": "Mem", "6": "Extended", "8": "Timecode"}, "cmd": "nothing", "load": 0, "deposit": [], "data": {"fixed": [], "open": 0}, "restirctions": {"start_button": 0, "keys": [{"ctrl-esc": 0}, {"alt-tab": 0}], "mouse": 1, "drives": [{"c": 0}, {"d": 0}], "desktop": 0, "task_manager": 0, "keyboard": 1, "taskbar": 0, "control_panel": 0}}
```

please guide me.. countless googles ive made and topics i have read.
the sample on json.net didnt even work

EDIT/UPDATE:

i'm now trying this one

```
List<WrapperReader> datas;

 datas = new JavaScriptSerializer(new SimpleTypeResolver()).Deserialize<List<WrapperReader>>(jsonInput);
```

}

but datas is empty, what may be the problem here?

**UPDATE 2**

i kind of figure whats making it to error

its the class.

if im going to receive a array of strings . then inside my class i must declare it as array to
same goes to decimals and dates

about dates.. if im going to receive a date. how do i declare it so it can contain a date?

im going to finish the coding see if its really the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi 
I wrote a basic example for you.
You can use without Json.NET library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerSurname { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.CustomerID + " " + this.CustomerName + " " + this.CustomerSurname;
    }
}

 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string JSonData = @"[
        {
             ""CustomerID"": ""1"",
             ""CustomerName"": ""Mehmet"",
             ""CustomerSurname"": ""Tasköprü""
        },
        {
             ""CustomerID"": ""2"",
             ""CustomerName"": ""Cin"",
             ""CustomerSurname"": ""Ali""
        },
        {
             ""CustomerID"": ""3"",
             ""CustomerName"": ""Temel"",
             ""CustomerSurname"": ""Reis""
        }]";

        IList<Customer> iListData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<IList<Customer>>(JSonData);

        foreach (var item in iListData)
            Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hi thankyou for the example , its been useful for me to make my own deserialized